# IE sees only the first ssl cert configured in nginx

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, nginx

I have a site under nginx configured this way (both domains on one IP):

```
server {
  listen   443;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/oldsite.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/oldsite.com.ca.key;

  server_name oldsite.ca;

  rewrite ^(.*) https://newsite.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen   443;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/newsite.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/newsite.com.ca.key;

  server_name newsite.com

  ...
}
```

For some reason IE (tried with IE9) does only see the first certificate configured, so if I go to https://newsite.com I get certificate invalid message with oldsite.com certificate presented.
If I change the order of server blocks, https://newsite.com works fine, but the redirect (rewrite) doesn't (now it sees only newsite.com cert, so of course it is complaining about it being invalid when hitting oldsite.com).

Any ideas, why (besides just being IE) it fails to see both certs for the respective domains?

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault.

Comment: Have you tried with other (modern) browsers? Is it on XP?

Answer (score 3):

You're visibly trying to use [Server Name Indication](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni), to be able to use multiple certificates on the same IP address/port combination. You should check that your version of nginx supports it (as described in the documentation).

This should be supported by IE 9 on Windows Vista and 7, but it's not supported on any version of IE on XP.